# Divergence of a series

Tags: divergent-series

I'd like to know if this proposition is true:

$$ \left\{ x_n \right\} | x_{n+1}>x_n \wedge \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \infty \Rightarrow $$ $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \left( 1 - \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1} }  \right) = \infty$$
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. You have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} = \ln x_{n+1} - \ln x_1 \to \infty.
$$
If $(x_{k+1}/x_k)$ does not converge to $1$, then the series trivially diverges because the terms do not converge to $0$. Otherwise you have $x_{k+1}/x_k \le 2$ eventually, and so
$$
\ln \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} \le \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}-1 \le 2 \left(1 - \frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}\right),
$$
implying your claim by comparison of series.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I am quite sure that the last inequality is false! That's because (a/b - 1 < 1- b/a ; a/b + b/a < 2 ; a*a + b*b < 2*a*b) and that's false!

Comment: Or you can, for example, consider x_k=2 and x_k+1=3 and you obtain 1/2<=1/3

Comment: @Ludox: Oops, that is true, but it is easy to fix.

Comment: This doesn't improve the answer. Now you can consider x_k=2 and x_k+1= 6 and you obtain 2<4/3

Comment: @Ludox: Read the statement just before the inequality. Either $x_{k+1} \le 2 x_k$ (for all sufficiently large $k$), or the series diverges by an easier argument.

Comment: You are right, my fault, sorry!